# LINQ: Get all objects with a matching string property from an incoming IEnumerable<string> in a performant way

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I just saw this piece of code and asked myself how it can be improved to reduce the amount of queries. Tried a few LINQ statements but could not find an answer.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, Computer> GetComputer(IEnumerable<string> workStations)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Computer>();
        using (var db = new ComputerContext())
        {
                foreach (var workStation in workStations)
                {
                    var t = db.Computers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id.Equals(workStation));

                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(workStation))
                    {
                        dict.Add(workStation, t);
                    }
                }

                return dict;
        }
    }
```

When trying someting like this:

```
var computers = db.Computers.Where(x => workStations.Select(y => y).Equals(x.Id)).ToList();

foreach (var computer in computers)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(computer.Id))
    {
        dict.Add(computer.Id, computer);
    }
}
```

Intellisense is telling me "Suspicious comparison: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' and 'string'" which
>   leds to an Exception "Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are
>   supported."

Comment: Id is just an example (it's a string in this example)

Comment: Yes, I got that. the problem is with the usage of `Select`. it basically does nothing in your code. it is like if your wrote `workStations.Equals(x.Id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your query. Try this code:

```
var computers = db.Computers.Where(x => workStations.Any(y => y.Equals(x.Id)).ToList();

foreach (var computer in computers)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(computer.Id))
    {
        dict.Add(computer.Id, computer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but unfortunately the old code is twice as fast (measured with Stopwatch)

Comment: What is the old code? This is just fixing your error. Basically, it looks query 10 times if workstation has 10 items

Comment: I meant the code which i posted in my question with multiple queries is twice as fast as the LINQ code.